# SPARQL Query DBpedia Getting Multiple Values

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am new to DBPedia SPARQL Query, I am currently using the http://dbpedia.org/snorql to test queries.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT ?name ?school ?person

WHERE {
    ?person dbo:almaMater :Harvard_University .
    ?person foaf:name ?name .
    ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth .
    ?person dbo:country ?country .
    ?person dbo:almaMater ?school .
    FILTER (?birth > "1980-01-01"^^xsd:date) . 
} ORDER BY ?name
```

And below is my result

[image]

From the result above, looks like the name "Mingze Xi"@en was repeated thrice. I checked on the link under the person field and it shows that name "Mingze Xi"@en has attended Harvard University, Hangzhou ... and Zhejiang University.

Is there a way for me to query and show that under this name the person has attended these schools? I need this because there is no unique ID that I can use to indicate that this is the same person.

Comment: Why do you say that there is no unique ID that can be used to indicate the person? that is exactly what the URI `:Xi_Mingze` is used for.

Comment: Those `Xi:Mingze` were all the same. But as you can see from my screenshot, there are 3 types of record for Xi Mingze.

Comment: I know, and the result is quite obvious since there are 3 different universities for `:Xi_Mingze`. the question is what you want now? Indeed you can identify on the client side that for each university the person is the same. Or what else do you want to know? All universities in one single row? If yes, how do you process this on the client side?